# Unable to connect to mysql using jbdc driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-string, mysql-connector

I'm trying to access an mysql database, but I'm getting following error :

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/...
```

I know this question have been asked already, but I haven't solved my issues with the solution in the existing topic. I reused a connection class that was working 2 years ago.

I changed my PC and reinstalled wamp and eclipse, and the exact same class with a good buildpath configuration doesn't work. Here is the code I use to connect:

```
Connection connection = null;
public java.sql.Statement stmt = null;
public java.sql.PreparedStatement prStmt;
public ResultSet rs = null;

public DbConnex(String sgbd, int port, String dbName, String user, String pass){

    String DbInfo = String.format("jdbc:%s//localhost:3306/%s", sgbd, dbName);//jdbc:mysql://address=(protocol=tcp)(host=localhost)(port=3306)/nekogame
                                                                              //jdbc:%s//localhost:3306/%s
    //test trouver le driver
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");

    //test connexion
    try {
        connection = DriverManager
        .getConnection(DbInfo, user, pass);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("it's all good!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection :( !");
    }
 }
```

Here is the output, which shows that my driver is recognized:

```
"MySQL JDBC Driver Registered! Connection Failed! Check output console"
```

The problem seems to happen on the `getConnection`. I verified the parameters, and downloaded the latest driver. I also have the latest wamp that should embed the latest MySQL. Now I don't know what to do.

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but, what MySql version you currently use, what IDE, (and did you changed your password for connecting to MySql as a Admin - root)?

Comment: Your parametrization of the JDBC sub-protocol doesn't make much sense, the `//localhost:3306/` binds you to MySQL (as 3306 is the default MySQL port), or databases that have a similar URL format and run on a (for that database) non-default port of 3306. If you parametrize, then parametrize the entire JDBC url, as apart from `jdbc:<subprotocol>:`-prefix, everything after the prefix is driver-specific.

Answer (score 1):

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/

Whereas correct connection string is, you have missed colon (**`:`**) just after `mysql`. So, it should be

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<dbname>
```

So, you need to make change here

```
String.format("jdbc:%s//localhost:3306/%s", sgbd, dbName);
```

instead, it should be

```
String.format("jdbc:%s://localhost:3306/%s", sgbd, dbName);
```

Just for reference, please refer [official page for connection string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

Comment: Nice one, @Ravi, I didn't even noticed missing colon.